# Reopen app to last activity

Tags: applications

If I open an app from a link (e.g. a notification or a link from an SMS), every subsequent time I open the app from the history, it goes back to the same link, performing actions I don't want it to and making me have to shut down the extra page / press back to clear the subitem(s). It becomes necessary to force-close the app and reopen it from the apps list to get the default behaviour back.

It there a way that when an app goes to sleep and is woken up again, it resumes from where it left off, and not from the last link used to open it?

#### EDIT

Some people are having trouble understanding the issue, so step by step:

1. Open an app from a notification or a link
2. Read the message, take any appropriate action, etc. then use the app normally, navigating away from the notification area
3. Wait half an hour or long enough for the OS to put the app to sleep
4. Open the recent tasks list
5. Select the app again to wake it up

Instead of the app remembering its last state (which it does when opened from the installed apps list), it reopens as if the notification had been clicked again.

I haven't noticed any apps that don't do this. Opera, Facebook, Duolingo, etc. It's on Android 7.0.

Comment: Apps will resume from sleep in the manner programmed to them. If the app is designed to forget its progress and stopping point upon resume, then that is what it will do. It CANNOT deviate; to do so would impart it with some form of AI, to which we will then have to battle for domination of the planet.

Comment: @wbogacz I don't believe that it's app dependant. I believe it's the OS that provides the way for the app to wake. Otherwise, starting it from the app list would exhibit the same behaviour, when it actually behaves differently.

Comment: @CJDennis wbogacz is right. Android has several different entry points for apps according to whether it was started from the task list, from a notification, from the launcher, etc. The behaviour also depends on how long it is since you last ran the app. It's up to the app developer to test all these different ways through the app lifecycle to make sure they do the expected thing each time, and it sounds like this app has a bug. What app is it? What Android version? And can you clarify "open the app from the history" - do you mean the recent tasks list?